# Getting a Leads "Status" from a Leads "Status Reason"

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Within Dynamics CRM the Lead entity has both a Status and a Status Reason. Using the API I can get all of the Status Reasons. Where I am getting tripped up is when my user selects a Status Reason I would like to work backwards and figure out which Status is associated with the selected Status Reason.

Here is how I get all of the Status Reasons:

```
 //get the list of status reasons 
 RetrieveAttributeRequest request = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
 request.EntityLogicalName = "lead";
 request.LogicalName = "statuscode";

 RetrieveAttributeResponse response = RetrieveAttributeResponse)theOrgContext.Execute(request);
StatusAttributeMetadata picklist = (StatusAttributeMetadata)response.AttributeMetadata;
 foreach (OptionMetadata option in picklist.OptionSet.Options)
 {
  retval.ListOfStatuses.Add(option.Value.Value, option.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label.ToString());
 }
```

And To update an entity I am just using LINQ:

```
 //set the status to the new value
 theLead.StatusCode.Value = int.Parse(statusValue);

theLead.StateCode = ???

//mark the object as updated
theContext.UpdateObject(theLead);

//persist the changes back to the CRM system
theContext.SaveChanges();
```

I just can't figure out how to query CRM to figure out what value I would need to put in for the ???

Comment: Before any one asks, we are allowing the customer to add more then just the default Status Reasons for a given Status. So I can not use the Enumerations that come with the LINQ entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the information for state with status.

```
RetrieveAttributeRequest req = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
req.EntityLogicalName = "lead";
req.LogicalName = "statuscode";
req.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;
RetrieveAttributeResponse res = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)yourContext.Execute(req);

StatusAttributeMetadata attribute = (StatusAttributeMetadata)res.AttributeMetadata;
foreach (StatusOptionMetadata oStatusOptionMetaData in attribute.OptionSet.Options)
{
    var state = oStatusOptionMetaData.State.Value;
    var status = oStatusOptionMetaData.Value.Value;
}
```